# Does Qt have a way to find bounding box of an image?

Tags: qt

Given a `.png` image with a transparent background, I want to find the bounding box of the non-transparent data.  Using nested `for` loops with `QImage.pixel()` is painfully slow.  Is there a built-in method of doing this in Qt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If pixel() is too slow for you, consider more efficient row-wise data adressing, given a QImage p:

```
int l =p.width(), r = 0, t = p.height(), b = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < p.height(); ++y) {
    QRgb *row = (QRgb*)p.scanLine(y);
    bool rowFilled = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < p.width(); ++x) {
        if (qAlpha(row[x])) {
            rowFilled = true;
            r = std::max(r, x);
            if (l > x) {
                l = x;
                x = r; // shortcut to only search for new right bound from here
            }
        }
    }
    if (rowFilled) {
        t = std::min(t, y);
        b = y;
    }
}
```

I doubt it will get any faster than this.

Comment: It's not like Qt docs are advertising it well. Took me half a year to find out about it.

Comment: I did a few rough timings of my over-all task without creating a micro-benchmark. This approach used essentially the same amount of cpu-time as Arnold's solution, but reduced wall-clock time.

Answer (score 5):

There is one option that involves using a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and querying for the bounding box of the opaque area (`QGraphicsPixmapItem::opaqueArea().boundingRect()`). Not sure if it is the best way but it works :) It might be worth digging into Qt's source code to see what code is at the heart of it.

The following code will print out the width and height of the image followed by the width and height of the opaque portions of the image:

```
QPixmap p("image.png");
QGraphicsPixmapItem *item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(p);
std::cout << item->boundingRect().width() << "," << item->boundingRect().height() << std::endl;
std::cout << item->opaqueArea().boundingRect().width() << "," << item->opaqueArea().boundingRect().height() << std::endl;
```

Comment: opaqueArea() constructs a whole Path describing the area. That should be slower than simple bounding rectangle computation.

Comment: Hopefully the OP can post some timing results. I'd be interested to see how much time both options take. But yes, for complicated images I can only imagine it being slower.

Comment: I did a few rough timings of my over-all task without creating a micro-benchmark.  This approach used essentially the same amount of wall-clock time as my nested for-loops, but took less cpu time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and congrats on your new voting power :)

Comment: I just stumbled over QGraphicsPixmapItem again and thought it was really nice that you pointed it out here. Furthermore if one does need the path of a QImage or QPixmap, they might not easily find that Qt provides the functionality in QGraphicsPixmapItem.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and also relatively fast solution is to do as follows:

```cpp
QRegion(QBitmap::fromImage(image.createMaskFromColor(0x00000000))).boundingRect()
```

If you have a `QPixmap` rather than `QImage`, then you can use:

```cpp
QRegion(pixmap.createMaskFromColor(Qt::transparent)).boundingRect()
```

`QPixmap::createMaskFromColor` internally will convert the pixmap to an image and do the same as above. An even shorter solution for `QPixmap` is:

```cpp
QRegion(pixmap.mask()).boundingRect()
```

In this case, a `QPixmap` without alpha channel will result in an empty region, so you may need to check for that explicitly. Incidentally, this is also what `QGraphicsPixmapItem::opaqueArea` mentioned by @Arnold Spence is based on.

You may also want to try `QImage::createAlphaMask`, though the cutoff point will not be at 0 alpha but rather somewhere at half opacity.